# Redirect to frontend login form after receiving email verification mail from CMS?

Tags: config, redirect, registration, frontend-form, verification

I'm working on a site with public registration and a manual approval flow for new users. The following settings for user accounts are active: **Verify email addresses**, **Allow public registration**, **Suspend users by default**. The workflow currently looks like this:

1. A new user uses the frontend registration form to register for an account.
2. An admin manually approves the account (using the **Unsuspend user** action).
3. The admin sends the activation email using the **Send activation email** action.

The problem is that since the activation email is sent from the CP, Craft appears to always use the CP-path for verification (so `/admin/verify-email` instead of `verifyemail`). The [`verifyEmailPath` config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#verifyemailpath) is ignored. And after clicking the verification link, the user is redirected to the CP login form instead of the frontend login form. The [`verifyEmailSuccessPath` config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#verifyemailsuccesspath) is ignored.

I guess the two options above only come into play if the verification email is sent automatically after the public registration (without manual approval). I haven't found a way to change the redirect for verification emails sent from the CP.

Is there a way to either change the path for email verification to the frontend path (`/verifyemail`) or change the redirect after verifying through the backend path (`/admin/verify-email`)?

Comment: That's because your new users have CP access in their permissions :)

Comment: @Oli Thanks, that's good to know! I wasn't sure why it works differently than another Craft site I built recently, but that makes perfect thanks. Though I would still like to redirect those users to the frontend login form instead of the backend form, so it would be great if there's a way to do that.

Comment: The relationships/interplay between the User concepts of "suspended", "activated", and "verified" definitely need some attention in the Craft documentation. These 3 things are separate-but-not-separate in obtuse ways. I've built quite a few sites that have front end membership and I get confused every time about the general setup.